# Toast and onOnclick, toast k won't show

Tags: android, onclick, toast

Does anyone know why this program won't show the toast message?

```
public class Main extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
/** Called when the activity is first created. */


  ImageButton x = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
  ImageButton i = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);
  ImageButton question = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton3);
```

I have crated some ImageButons and other elements and created onClick function

```
public void onClick(View v) {
            if(v.getId() == R.id.button1) // this works 
            {
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, Second.class);
                intent.putExtra("thetext", et1.getText().toString());
                intent.putExtra("thesize", et2.getText().toString());
                startActivity(intent);
            }
            if(v.getId() == R.id.imageButton2) // this wont work 
            {
                Toast toastI = Toast.makeText(this, "Testing", 5000);
                toastI.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
                toastI.show();
            }
```

When i Click on ImageButton i(after i run program) the toast won't display?

Answer (score 1):

Hope you have set the onclickListener on imagebuttons..

```
  i.setOnClickListener(this);
```

try this

```
Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "Testing", 5000).show();
```

Comment: The third argument to the `Toast` method is what is causing the problem. The third argument may only be `Toast.LENGTH_SHORT` or `Toast.LENGTH_LONG`. It won't work if you pass it `5000`.

Comment: i forget to set onclickListener on imagebuttons, so now after i did that, it works as it should

Answer (score 0):

try using `switch` case instead of `if` and use `Main.this` or `getApplicationContext()` instead of `this` as:

```
public void onClick(View v) {

switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.button1:
    Intent intent = new Intent(Main, Second.class);
            intent.putExtra("thetext", et1.getText().toString());
            intent.putExtra("thesize", et2.getText().toString());
            startActivity(intent);
    break;
    case R.id.imageButton3:
        Toast toastI = Toast.makeText(Main.this, "Testing", 5000);
        toastI.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
        toastI.show();
    break;
 }
}
```

Comment: The third argument to the `Toast` method is what is causing the problem. The third argument may only be `Toast.LENGTH_SHORT` or `Toast.LENGTH_LONG`. It won't work if you pass it `5000`.

Comment: i forget to set onclickListener on imagebuttons, so now after i did that, it works as it should

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is putting 5000 on the length of the toast. [LENGTH_LONG](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toast.html#LENGTH_LONG) and [LENGTH_SHORT](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toast.html#LENGTH_SHORT) have values 1 and 0 so they are used as flags. So I don't know what Would happen if you put 5000 (probably nothing). Also on the java doc they say you should put or or the other. So use one or the other.

> public static Toast makeText (Context context, CharSequence text, int
>   duration)  Since: API Level 1  Make a standard toast that just
>   contains a text view.
>
> Parameters context  The context to use. Usually your Application or
>   Activity object.  text  The text to show. Can be formatted text. 
>   duration  How long to display the message. Either LENGTH_SHORT or
>   LENGTH_LONG

Comment: i forget to set onclickListener on imagebuttons, so now after i did that, it works as it should

Answer (score 0):

`static Toast makeText(Context context, int resId, int duration)`

The problem is that you are passing `5000` as the third parameter to the method. `int duration` is *not* the number of seconds (or milli-seconds) the `Toast` will appear to the user. The `Toast` class requires that you pass only two possible values (which makes sense, because otherwise developers would totally abuse the lengths of toast messages and the applications on the Android market would be totally inconsistent in how they display messages to the user). The two values are:

```
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT 
Constant Value: 0 (0x00000000)
```

or

```
Toast.LENGTH_LONG`
Constant Value: 1 (0x00000001)
```

To fix the issue, change the method call to,

```
Toast.makeText(this, "Testing", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

---

Also, remember to set your `onClickListener` on your `ImageButton`s (just a shot in the dark).

Comment: i forget to set onclickListener on imagebuttons, so now after i did that, it works as it should

Answer (score 0):

First  implements View.OnClickListener interface and add listener to each imagebutton like this :

x.setOnClickListener(this);

- for the toast message the code mjst be like this :

Toast.makeText(Main.this,"put your message here",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();